# Javascript : loading of a local file leads to a 404 error(scala+spray)

Tags: javascript, jquery, scala

I'm creating a project using `spray`(in scala), `twirl`(like play! templates), and the usual web stuff(html, javascript, jquery).

The problem comes from the download of local files using javascript.
Here is the JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="easy.notification.js"></script>
```

The web call is a get call, with the `URI="http://localhost:8080/easy.notification.js"`

The file is in the same directory as twirl files, but the previous request leads to a 404 error.
Is this a wrong directory(I know the the twirl files are compiled to scala).
What is the good one?